# Untracked files show up after failed git pull

Tags: git

I started with a clean working directory.

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Then I did a git pull that failed with two permissions errors:

```
error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore' (Permission denied)
fatal: cannot create directory at 'vendor': Permission denied
```

And suddenly there are many untracked files in my working directory that were not there before.

I have tried resolving the permissions issue that makes the pull fail in the first place but can anyone explain to me why untracked files are being put into my project folder locally?

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Can you provide untracked file examples?

Comment: I cannot because they are sensitive data. They are PHP, json, and image files that are part of commits located on the remote I was pulling from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like git failed during its pull process because of the file permissions.

I ran a `strace` on a failing process, and it shows that despite the "Permission denied" error, git keeps on trying to write the other files.
Later, since it had errors, it doens't finish the merge process, leaving the local repository in its previous state: instead of renaming `.git/index.lock` to `.git/index` (when merge is successful), it simply removes `.git/index.lock`.

What you can do from here is a `git reset --hard` then pull again, since your local was clean at the beginning.